# How to use the trace of matrix to prove this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A,B$ be a square matrix of order $n$ and $$A B - B A = A^m$$ where $m \geqslant 1$. Prove that $|A|=0$.

---

I got that

$$\mathrm{tr}(A^m)=\mathrm{tr}(AB-BA)=\mathrm{tr}(AB)-\mathrm{tr}(BA)=0$$

but I don't know the next steps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $A$ were invertible, you'd have $ABA^{-m} - BAA^{-m} = I$. But $\operatorname{tr} ABA^{-m} = \operatorname{tr} BA^{-m}A = \operatorname{tr} BAA^{-m}$, while $\operatorname{tr} I \ne 0$ (presuming the characteristic of the field is zero).